# How to display validation error message as a tooltip on hover of error icon in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap validation inside an ionic application. It works fine, it shows the error icon within the textbox and error message under the textbox. How can I change it to show the error message as tooltip when hovering over the error icon within the textbox? I do not want to show the error message under the textbox.

Comment: how are you using bootstrap in your ionic / angular app ? Are using boostrap library directly, referencing the bootstrap scss, or maybe ng-boostrap  ?

Comment: Hi thanks for response.i installed bootstrap in ionic project and made changes in package.json and variable.scss

Comment: thats a bad Idea to use Bootstrap in your ionic project. you might get css uses later. avoid using bootstrap in your project? and use ReactiveForms to show your errors below input fields.

Answer (score 0):

i am able to display validation error message as a tooltip on hover of error icon in ionic using angular material tooltip. please find below code

```
<ion-col size="12">
          <ion-item lines="none">
            <ion-label>Name</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item line="inset">
            <ion-input formControlName="name">
            </ion-input>
            <mat-icon [ngStyle]="{'color':'#dc3545'}" class="error-icon"
              *ngIf="empForm.get('name')?.errors && addQuationForm.get('name')?.touched"
              matTooltip="Name is required">error
            </mat-icon>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
```

Note: dont forget to add angular material tooltip module and Mat icon module to your current working module import section like

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [MatTooltipModule,MatIconModule],
  exports: [],
})
export class AppModule { }
```